# Configuring Jelly Script to show all changes since last successful build

Tags: jenkins, jelly, email-ext

I'm looking to alter the default jelly script that comes with the email-ext plugin for Jenkins. At current it will show all changes made to the SVN repo between each build, but it would be preferable to show all changes between each successful build. i.e.

```
Build 1, successful : email sent to team
Commit 1
Build 2, failed : email sent to committer, showing commit 1
Commit 2 to fix commit 1
Build 3, successful : email sent to team, showing commit 1 & commit 2
```

As opposed to the current method, where the build 3 notification would only show commit 2.

The template pulls the data with the following:

```
<j:set var="changeSet" value="${build.changeSet}" />
```

But is it possible to alter this to go back to the last successful build?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the email-ext groovy email templates.

Then, copy the sample [`groovy-html.template`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template) and add this script around line 30.

```
def lastSuccessfulBuild = project.lastSuccessfulBuild

for(int i = lastSuccessfulBuild.number; i <= build.number; i++)
{
  def changeSet = project.getBuildByNumber(i).changeSet
}
```